# Extract the first TRUE per row in logical matrix efficiently in R

Tags: r, matrix

Given the following matrix:

```
         A     B    C
[1,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
[6,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE

m <- structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), .Dim = c(6L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B", "C")))
```

How we can extract the first column with TRUE value per row **efficiently**? Of course, we could use `apply` per row and then get the `min(which(...))`.

Here is the desired output:

```
[1] A B C B B A
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236169) might seem a duplicate of my question but its not:

1. Here we are talking about a **logical matrix** NOT a numeric data frame
2. Here we seek to get the position of the first TRUE not the highest value

Comment: @Steven I disagree.  Firstly that question was about data frames, not matrices.  Secondly, this question asking about how to find the *first* true element in a row, rather than merely the maximum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `max.col`

```
colnames(m)[max.col(m, "first")]
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "B" "B" "A"
```

If there are no TRUE in a row, then we can change it to `NA` (if needed)

```
colnames(m)[max.col(m, "first")*NA^!rowSums(m)]
```

Or with `ifelse`

```
colnames(m)[ifelse(rowSums(m)==0, NA, max.col(m, "first"))]
```

Comment: Seems like even this method is a [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275212/max-col-with-na-removal/39275278#39275278) of yours

Comment: An alternative to the `ifelse` would be to `cbind` a dummy column to the end which is all `TRUE`.  `m <- cbind(m, none = TRUE)`.  Then run `colnames(m)[max.col(m, "first")]`.

Answer (score 7):

Another vision, using `which` to work with the `logical` class of the matrix:

```
colnames(m)[aggregate(col~row, data=which(m, arr.ind = TRUE), FUN=min)$col]
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "B" "B" "A"
```

We get the indices of the `TRUE` values and then find the minimum (index of) column in which they occur, by row.

**benchmark**

```
library(microbenchmark)
n <- matrix(FALSE, nrow=1000, ncol=500) # couldn't afford a bigger one...
n <- t(apply(n, 1, function(rg) {rg[sample(1:500, 1, replace=TRUE)] <- TRUE ; rg}))
colnames(n) <- paste0("name", 1:500)
akrun <- function(n){colnames(n)[max.col(n, "first")]}
cath <- function(n){colnames(n)[aggregate(col~row, data=which(n, arr.ind = TRUE), FUN=min)$col]}

all(akrun(n)==cath(n))
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark(akrun(n), cath(n))
# expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#akrun(n)  6.985716  7.233116  8.231404  7.525513  8.842927 31.23469   100  a 
# cath(n) 18.416079 18.811473 19.586298 19.272398 20.262169 22.42786   100   b
```

Comment: Better to compare the output of functions (if they are identical) on which we do benchmarking.

Comment: I did mean if `akrun(n)==cath(n)`. I did not get what you mean, but ok. its friday.....

Comment: Then my first comment :-)

Comment: @m0h3n ok, I think it is finally ok and both results are not NULL and identical :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is my attempt. It isn't a one-liner, but it is lightning fast.

```
joe <-  function(x) {
    y <- which(x)
    nR <- nrow(x)
    myR <- y %% nR
    myR[myR==0] <- nR
    myNames <- colnames(x)[ceiling(y/nR)]
    myCols <- which(!(duplicated(myR)))
    myNames[myCols][order(myR[myCols])]
}
```

Here are the benchmarks using the data provided by @Cath:

```
microbenchmark(akrun(n), cath(n), joe(n))
Unit: microseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
akrun(n)  4248.760  5588.8640  6148.1816  5926.7130  6378.887 12502.437   100
 cath(n) 12641.189 13733.1415 14808.6524 14532.8115 15559.287 20628.037   100
  joe(n)   555.418   642.2405   758.5293   713.2585   800.697  4849.334   100

all.equal(akrun(n), cath(n), joe(n))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: good attempt. interesting it maintains better speed. +1

Comment: @m0h3n, I too was surprised at the speed. I haven't looked at the source code for `max.col`, but I'm guessing there is some unnecessary overhead. Btw, this was a great question!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way that has a better performance w.r.t. @Cath solutions:

```
a <- which(m, arr.ind = T)
colnames(m)[aggregate(col~row,a[order(a[,1]),],min)$col]

# [1] "A" "B" "C" "B" "B" "A"
```

Benchmarking given the matrix used by @Cath:

```
m0h3n <- function(m){
   a <- which(m, arr.ind = T)
   colnames(m)[aggregate(col~row,a[order(a[,1]),],min)$col]
}

all.equal(akrun(n), cath(n), joe(n), m0h3n(n))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(akrun(n), cath(n), joe(n), m0h3n(n))

# Unit: microseconds
     # expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 # akrun(n) 2291.981 2395.793 2871.7156 2482.7790 3561.9150  4205.370   100
  # cath(n) 8263.210 8554.665 9695.9375 8782.8710 9947.9415 58239.983   100
   # joe(n)  274.029  298.517  526.6722  312.0375  342.5355  2366.798   100
 # m0h3n(n) 3890.178 3974.309 4280.6677 4073.1635 4227.7550  6337.501   100
```

**Therefore, here is the ranked solutions (in terms of efficiency):**

1. **joe**
2. **akrun**
3. **m0h3n**
4. **Cath**

Comment: It's amazing at what a little order will do for you. +1